# Using an if in case

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn Scala and attempting to write a function that uses a case statement(switch) to be able to determine if a number is odd or even. Any idea where I have my syntax wrong?

```
val y = List(1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 15)
```

```
def oddEven(y: Int) = y match {

    case y if y % 2 ==0 => 2
    case y if y %2 != 0 => 4
    case _ => 0
 }
```

Comment: There is no error. Can you specify exactly what error you faced?

Comment: useful links:
1) https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html
2) https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html.html
3) https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be:

```
def oddEven(y: Int) = y match {
    case x if x % 2 == 0 => 2
    case _ => 4
 }
```

Because there are only 2 cases *even* or *odd*.

I would take other names for the case variables (for example `x`  instead of `y`).

```
List(1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 15).map(oddEven) // > List(4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4)
```

If there are only 2 cases `if-else` might be more readable:

```
def oddEven(y: Int) =
  if(y % 2 == 0) 2 else 4
```